# aes_encrypt() function hooking

Tags: aes, reverse-engineering

I want to know the pid of the process which is performing the AES encryption. I have written the following function hooking code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

void AES_encrypt(const unsigned char *in_var, unsigned char *out_var,
const AES_KEY *key_var)
{
  void (*new_aes_encrypt)(const unsigned char *in_var, unsigned char *out_var,
  const AES_KEY *key_var);

  new_aes_encrypt = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "AES_encrypt");
  FILE *logfile = fopen("logfile", "a+");
  fprintf(logfile, "Process %d:nn%snnn", getpid(), (char *)in_var);
  fclose(logfile);
  new_aes_encrypt(in_var, out_var, key_var);
}
```

Then at terminal I did the followings:

```
#gcc aes_hook.c -o aes_hook.so -fPIC -shared -lssl -D_GNU_SOURCE 
#export LD_PRELOAD="/<directory location>/aes_hook.so"
```

However, when I started the AES encryption (by a dummy process), I could not get it's pid in logfile. Why is this hooking not working?

*P.S.: Following is the declaration of AES_encrypt (in aes.h of OpenSSL) function that is called to perform the AES encryption.

```
void AES_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
    const AES_KEY *key)
```

Comment: Possibly a dumb question, but you did run the AES-encrypting program from the same terminal, right?

Comment: Thanks for your quick and shrewd response (at least justify your reputation). By the way, I didn't run the dummy program (performing the AES encryption) in the same terminal. I'm assuming there are hundreds of CPU cores and AES can be performed on any one of those.

Comment: export only set the variable in the same terminal session. If you start from other terminal, ld_preload won't be set

Comment: @Krypton What if the process running AES is in a different terminal? Is it possible to find out it's PID by another process?

Comment: Also FYI, almost all of my reputation on this site is from one answer.

Comment: @Scissor The process/terminal running AES has to have the `LD_PRELOAD` set so that it will load your `aes_hook.so`.  Running it in a different terminal means that it won't know to load your hook.

Comment: @RoraΖ I referred to this link (https://blog.netspi.com/function-hooking-part-i-hooking-shared-library-function-calls-in-linux/)  and I was able to get the pid of the process accessing HTTPS urls (SSL). I tried to implement the similar thing for AES. What should I do to get the pid of any process that is performing AES encryption?

Comment: The only way I can think of might be to insert the path of your library at the beginning of LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Which might be used for all processes.  You might have to reboot for it to take affect.  I think StackOverflow would give you a better answer.

Comment: I don't think this question should be on StackOverflow. People at SO won't care about hooking.